# Learning Dynamic Quiz Javascript and have questions

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm following javascriptissexy and learning how to make a dynamic quiz. I found someone's own version of the quiz and looked at the source code to learn how they approached the problem; after I took a crack at it. I understand the html/css and some of the javascript code but need some questions answered. I was hoping someone can answer some questions I have about their source code. My questions are at the bottom.

Here's the link to the full app http://codepen.io/gcarino/pen/LDgtn/

And here's the full javascript code:

```
(function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "What is 2*5?",
    choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
    correctAnswer: 2
  }, {
    question: "What is 3*6?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*9?",
    choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is 1*7?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*8?",
    choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }];

  var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
  var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
  var quiz = $('#quiz'); //Quiz div object

  // Display initial question
  displayNext();

  // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
    choose();

    // If no user selection, progress is stopped
    if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
      alert('Please make a selection!');
    } else {
      questionCounter++;
      displayNext();
    }
  });

  // Click handler for the 'prev' button
  $('#prev').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    choose();
    questionCounter--;
    displayNext();
  });

  // Click handler for the 'Start Over' button
  $('#start').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {
      return false;
    }
    questionCounter = 0;
    selections = [];
    displayNext();
    $('#start').hide();
  });

  // Animates buttons on hover
  $('.button').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
  $('.button').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });

  // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and 
  // the answer selections
  function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);

    return qElement;
  }

  // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
  function createRadios(index) {
    var radioList = $('<ul>');
    var item;
    var input = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questions[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
  function choose() {
    selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
  }

  // Displays next requested element
  function displayNext() {
    quiz.fadeOut(function() {
      $('#question').remove();

      if(questionCounter < questions.length){
        var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
        quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
        if (!(isNaN(selections[questionCounter]))) {
          $('input[value='+selections[questionCounter]+']').prop('checked', true);
        }

        // Controls display of 'prev' button
        if(questionCounter === 1){
          $('#prev').show();
        } else if(questionCounter === 0){

          $('#prev').hide();
          $('#next').show();
        }
      }else {
        var scoreElem = displayScore();
        quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
        $('#next').hide();
        $('#prev').hide();
        $('#start').show();
      }
    });
  }

  // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
  function displayScore() {
    var score = $('<p>',{id: 'question'});

    var numCorrect = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
      if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
        numCorrect++;
      }
    }

    score.append('You got ' + numCorrect + ' questions out of ' +
                 questions.length + ' right!!!');
    return score;
  }
})();
```

My questions:

1) in regard to this block of code

```
 // Click handler for the 'next' button
  $('#next').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Suspend click listener during fade animation
    if(quiz.is(':animated')) {        
      return false;
    }
```

1.a What is e or (e) in the function parameter and what does e.preventDefault() do?

1.b How does return false suspend the click listener during the fade animation?

2) In regards to this block of code:

```
function createQuestionElement(index) {
    var qElement = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    qElement.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    qElement.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
    qElement.append(radioButtons);

    return qElement;
  }
```

1.a What is (index) in the function parameter? I see is used in the function body but don't know what it is referenced to in the html or js code.

I think that's it for now. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a - `e` is a variable referencing the event arguments. `e.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event action from completing - in this case, it will prevent the `click` action from firing off.

1b - Returning false from a jQuery event handler prevents the event from firing and prevents the event from bubbling up. (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) for more info)

2 If you look in the `displayNext` function, the `questionCounter` appears to be tracking the total number of questions. So when `createQuestionElement` is called, it is passed this `questionCounter` as a parameter (which is the number of the next question being created)

Comment: 1a. I see, then what's the point of preventing the click function if the goal in this script is to fire the click function on click. I see the author has a choose() function that pushes the value to the array but that isn't inside the click event function, or is it?

Comment: @Garuuk The author is preventing any default behavior from the click event because he is implementing his own functionality for the event. Yes, the `choose()` function is inside of the click event.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I misread where the closing } of the function was! Makes sense! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.a) `e` is the `eventObject` , and `e.preventDefault()` method stops the default action of an element from happening, in this case, the click.

1.b) `return false` in a click event also stops click from doing default action, which may be opening an url

2) `index` is a parameter sent from another block of code, in this case if you check whole code, it says: `var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);` so index in this case is the number of next question to show

Answer (score 1):

1.a) Using e is just a short for event. You can pass any variable name you desire. e.preventDefault(); will stop the default action of the event. In this case, its click.

1.b) By returning false, you are preventing the remaining part of the code from firing. Once the browser comes across return false, it won't execute the remaining part of the code below it.

2) Index is an argument to the function. You will pass the argument while calling the function.

In this case:

```
var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
```

Calls the function by passing questions index.

As you can see,

```
var questions = [{
    question: "What is 2*5?",
    choices: [2, 5, 10, 15, 20],
    correctAnswer: 2
  },  {
    question: "What is 3*6?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }]
```

Questions is an array, so you are passing the index to createRadio method to refer the same question there to construct the radio buttons as per the choices provided.